# Compiler Error: Stack too deep, try removing local variables

Tags: solidity, gnosis-safe, safe-core

Defined an interface

```
 interface ISafe {
 function encodeTransactionData(
    address to,
    uint256 value,
    bytes calldata data,
    Enum.Operation operation,
    uint256 safeTxGas,
    uint256 baseGas,
    uint256 gasPrice,
    address gasToken,
    address refundReceiver,
    uint256 _nonce
) external view returns (bytes memory);
```

}

When i am trying to access that, it is giving "CompilerError: Stack too deep, try removing local variables"

```
    bytes memory txHashData =  ISafe(msg.sender).encodeTransactionData(
                // Transaction info
                to,
                value,
                data,
                operation,
                safeTxGas,
                // Payment info
                baseGas,
                gasPrice,
                gasToken,
                refundReceiver,
                // Signature info
                nonce
            );
```

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

What's the significance of the interface? is a necessity? if it isn't then i suggest you use a struct and push to the struct in the contract of the function you're interfacing.
These errors occur when you have too much function arguments, local variables, or return values in a function. You can't reduce your function arguments, so pass the values in by pushing them to a struct instead.
If you're not satisfied with this answer let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are using too many parameter in your external functions or too many return values. To avoid you can change scope of the method to internal.
[Refer to this article for more info](https://soliditydeveloper.com/stacktoodeep).

Comment: Its an interface so cannot make the function internal

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `function()` is taking too many **independent** variables. To solve this, you can pack all (or some of them) into a structure.

So instead of your function receiving ten variables.  It would receive a single struct with ten properties.

A simple example where I pack 24 values into a function call:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity 0.8.3;

contract StackTooDeepSolution {

    // Struct containing eight variables
    struct Numbers {
        uint one;
        uint two;
        uint three;
        uint four;
        uint five;
        uint six;
        uint seven;
        uint eight;
    }
    
    // A function call with 3 structures (8x3 = 24 variables)
    function addData(Numbers memory firstNum, Numbers memory secondNum, Numbers memory thirdNum) external view returns (uint sum) {

        sum = firstNum.one + firstNum.two + firstNum.three + firstNum.four + firstNum.five + firstNum.six + firstNum.seven + firstNum.eight;
        sum += secondNum.one + secondNum.two + secondNum.three + secondNum.four + secondNum.five + secondNum.six + secondNum.seven + secondNum.eight;
        sum += thirdNum.one + thirdNum.two + thirdNum.three + thirdNum.four + thirdNum.five + thirdNum.six + thirdNum.seven + thirdNum.eight;
    }


}
```